# How to store/append code for later use

Tags: tex-core, etoolbox, box, parbox

To store some code for later use, I can think of two ways: `\appto` from `etoolbox` and `\sbox`.
They both have some problems in use.

For `\appto`, later invoke of a macro will cover the value of the former, as shown with `\ww` in ``Test 1''.

For `\sbox`, all macros in code will expand immediately. This is inconvenient when the value of a macro has to be given later  as `\parboxheightb` does in Test 4.

So, how to solve the above problems?
And how to use `\appto` in nested macro(pls see the example in Test 5).
Another question:  Why does `\\` in code of Test 3 not work?

**MWE:**

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{xcolor,pgf,etoolbox}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{showframe}
    \geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
    \parindent0pt
    \begin{document}
    Test 1: Later invoke of \verb|\ww| covers the value of the former invoke.\par
    \newcommand\testa{
      \def\do{}
      \def\ww{2pt}
      \appto\do{\rule{1in}{\ww}\\}
      \def\ww{10pt}
      \appto\do{\rule{1in}{\ww}}
    }
    \testa\do
    
    Test 2: In this way, the value of \verb|\parboxheighta| can be given after \verb|appto|\par
    \newdimen\parboxheighta
    \def\do{}
    \newcommand\testc[1]{
      \appto\do{\fbox{\parbox[t][\parboxheighta]{#1}{first}}}
    }
    \testc{1in}\testc{2in}
    \setlength{\parboxheighta}{2in}
    \do
    
    Test 3: Why does \verb|\\| in code not work?\par
    \newcommand\testb{
      \sbox0{}
      \def\ww{2pt}
      \sbox0{\usebox0\rule{1in}{\ww}\\}
      \def\ww{10pt}
      \sbox0{\usebox0\rule{1in}{\ww}}
    }
    \testb\usebox0
    
    \iffalse
    Test 4: In this way, the value of \verb|\parboxheightb| is given after \verb|appto| which causes error.\par
    \newdimen\paboxheightb
    \sbox0{}
    \newcommand\testd[1]{
      \sbox0{\usebox0\parbox[t][\paboxheightb]{#1}{second}}
    }
    \setlength{\parboxheightb}{2in}
    \testb{1in}\testb{2in}\usebox0
    \fi

\iffalse
Test 5：How to use \verb|\appto| in nested macro?
\def\mycolor{red}
\def\mylength{1in}
\def\myexe{}
\appto\myexe{\colorbox}
\eappto\myexe{{\mycolor}}
\eappto\myexe{\{}
\appto\myexe{\parbox}
\eappto\myexe{{\mylength}}
\eappto\myexe{{xxx}}
\eappto\myexe{\}}
\myexe
\fi
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Expansion: Macros are pointers, as I understand it. When test A's `do` runs, the contents of `\ww` have already been reset to `10pt` (per the definition). The question becomes: how to add the expanded value of `\ww` *at the time of definition*, such that the definition becomes, in effect, `  \appto\dota{\rule{1in}{2pt}\\}
 \appto\dota{\rule{1in}{10pt}}`?

Comment: @Cicada Yes, it is. However, in some cases,  the expansion of a macro has to be done later, as `\parboxheightb` does in "Test 4".

Comment: Test A: `\appto\do{\rule{1in}}
   \eappto\do{{\ww}\\}` expands at definition time.

Comment: I find that macro languages can be thought of as: There is only one definition (compile) and only one invocation (execute), because the name of the memory address (the macro name), called however many *x* times, does not of itself change the contents of the memory address (a parameter or equivalent would alter the address contents though, because the definition contains a variable, e.g., #2).

Comment: For Test C, define the `\do` inside `\testc`: `\newcommand\testc[1]{
 \def\do{}
  \appto\do{\fbox{\parbox[t][\parboxheighta]{#1}{xxx}}}
}`

Comment: Many thanks Cicada! Would you have any suggestion for  `Test 4` and `Test 5` of my code?

Comment: I don't understand 4 and 5 (yet). Aren't they just derivatives of the others? What is the expected output supposed to look like?

Comment: For Test 5, I want to get this code `\colorbox{red}{\parbox{1in}{xxx}}` by `\appto` , but failed because I don't know how to handle the second pair of brace of `\colorbox` by `\appto`. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134060/discussion-between-lyl-and-cicada).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: tests]

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,pgf,etoolbox}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{showframe}
\geometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
Test 1: Later invoke of \verb|\ww| covers the value of the former invoke.\par

Use \verb|\eappto|:\par

\newcommand\testa{
  \def\do{}
  \def\ww{2pt}
   \appto\do{\rule{1in}}
   \eappto\do{{\ww}\\}
  \def\ww{10pt}
  \appto\do{\rule{1in}{\ww}}
}

\testa\do
%\show\ww


Test 2: In this way, the value of \verb|\parboxheighta| can be given after \verb|appto|\par
Do \verb|\def\do{}| inside \verb|\testc|:\par
\newdimen\parboxheighta
\newcommand\testc[1]{
    \def\do{}
  \appto\do{\fbox{\parbox[t][\parboxheighta]{#1}{xxx}}}
}
\setlength{\parboxheighta}{1in}
\testc{1in}\do
\setlength{\parboxheighta}{2in}
\testc{1in}\do

Test 3: Why does \verb|\\| in code not work?\par
\newcommand\testb{
  \sbox0{}
  \def\ww{2pt}
  \sbox0{\rule{1in}{\ww}}
  \def\ww{10pt}
  \sbox0{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\usebox0\\\rule{1in}{\ww}\end{minipage}}
}
\testb\usebox0

\verb|\sbox| uses LR mode (no linebreaks): insert a minipage: see \texttt{texdoc latex2e}.

%\iffalse
%Test 4: In this way, the value of \verb|\parboxheightb| is given after \verb|appto| which causes error.\par
%\newdimen\paboxheightb
%\sbox0{}
%\newcommand\testd[1]{
%  \sbox0{\usebox0\parbox[t][\paboxheightb]{#1}{second}}
%}
%\setlength{\parboxheightb}{2in}
%\testb{1in}\testb{2in}\usebox0
%\fi
\end{document}
```